# How do I properly earth this voltage regulator that only has a two-prong plug?

Tags: earth

I have this automatic voltage regulator (AVR) that powers some audio equipment.

[image: Front of the AVR]

The problem is that it only comes with a two-prong plug so it isn't properly earthed. [image: two prong plug]

This means that the people who are using the equipment like microphones will sometimes get an electrical shock to their lips.

Other AVRs available in my country also don't have the third ground prong either so purchasing a new one isn't an option.

It seems to me that the terminal on the lower left corner of the back of the AVR is a ground terminal that I can theoretically connect to earth.

[image: Back of the AVR]

My question is that since my mains electrical outlet has an earth, can this terminal be connected to that hole by some sort of cable? Or should I just connect the terminal with the pipes under the sink?

[image: Is this the way]

Comment: Have you got a technical manual link for the voltage regulator box?

Comment: Why it is important to have such a voltage regulator in the system to begin with?

Comment: @Andyaka I took some pics of the manual [https://dl3.pushbulletusercontent.com/1PwhgLvogtLzjj0JALfhE0Qm2NawdlyC/20201205_231527.jpg](Wiring Diagram) [https://dl3.pushbulletusercontent.com/aa0p7KCUIE2xRtzAlTWqVJhtvM0wfIRn/20201205_231443.jpg](Working Principle)

Comment: @Justme Good question. It's just something we're used to having for sensitive equipment. Conventional wisdom in my country is that our electric supply isn't so stable, hence the AVR. But it's worth validating whether that's really true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nicest way would be to open up the unit, remove the 2-core wire currently fitted, and re-wire it with a 3-core wire and a 3-pin plug,  Connect the ground wire to a suitable screw inside the chassis.

A simpler and less elegant way would be to remove the 2-pin plug, and replace it with a 3-pin plug.  Run a separate ground wire to the terminal you have identified.

But check whether or not the manufacturer has bothered to connect up the ground terminals on the output sockets.  If not, they need to be connected as well.